# Invalid operands to binary expression ('RadioDevice' and 'const RadioDevice')

Tags: c++, c++11

I stuck badly on this issue, I am trying to find an object in list using find(). Below is the code:

```
std::vector<RadioDevice> radioDevices;
public:
void add(CartesianLocation location, std::list<RadioSignal<RadioDevice>> observedSignals){
    for(RadioSignal<RadioDevice> radioSignal : observedSignals) {
        if (std::find(radioDevices.begin(),
                      radioDevices.end(),
                      radioSignal.getRadioDevice()) != radioDevices.end()) {
            radioDevices.push_back(radioSignal.getRadioDevice());
        }
    }
}
```

RadioSignal extends RadioDevice which is an pure abstract class.
I am getting below error at `if (*__first == __value_) in find()`

> Invalid operands to binary expression ('RadioDevice' and 'const RadioDevice')

Comment: What does the `operator ==` for `RadioDevice` look like?

Comment: RadioDevice is a pure virtual class. class RadioDevice {
public:
    virtual std::string getMacAddress();
    
    virtual RadioDeviceType getType();
    
    virtual double getFrequency();
    
    virtual std::string getIdentifier();
    
    virtual void setIdentifier(std::string identifier);
    
    virtual int getTxPower();
    
};

Comment: `std::find` requires that you have defined a `operator==` for the types it works on. So you'll need to define one.

Comment: @TarunGupta Please add code to the question, not in comments.

Comment: @TarunGupta Then you are going to have more problems then just `std::find`  Since you only store `RadioDevice` instances instead of pointers you are slicing all of the objects.

Comment: @molbdnilo I will keep in mind, Thanks

Comment: @Zack can we have operator== in abstract class? Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, assuming you have a class `RadioDevice` defined as:

```
class RadioDevice {
public:
  virtual std::string getMacAddress();
  virtual RadioDeviceType getType();
  virtual double getFrequency();
  virtual std::string getIdentifier();
  virtual void setIdentifier(std::string identifier);
  virtual int getTxPower();
};
```

You'll need to define an `operator==` for your `RadioDevice` class. You can do that by adding

```
bool operator==(const RadioDevice& rhs, const RadioDevice& lhs) {
  return rhs.getIdentifier() == lhs.getIdentifier();
}
```

but, this assumes that two `RadioDevice` objects are equal if they have the same identifiers.

Comment: Doing so, gives me this error- Overloaded 'operator==' must be a binary operator (has 3 parameters). Don't know where I may be wrong

Comment: In the example I gave, operator== is a free function, not located in a class definition.

Comment: Thanks Zack, I understood late but this solved my problem.